# Bad character encoding in LoadRunner

Tags: character-encoding, loadrunner, siebel

When I record a siebel script, and then run it, I get `Status Error` with code of error and message like this:

`\xce\xe1\xff\xf7\xe0\xf2\xe5\xeb\xf2\xed\xfb\xe9 ........`

What character encoding is it and how can I decode it to normal text? I think that it's some Russian text, that describe error, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found answer. It's just a simple win1251 that shows up like utf8, but with \x.

Answer (score 0):

"When i record siebel script, and then run it"

You have a lot of handling of dynamic data before it will run successfully.   Record and replay is a myth, and a particularly large one with Siebel and LoadRunner